# Journal asks me to combine Latex files into single file

Tags: include, journal-publishing, journal

I am writing an article consisting of multiple sections. For each section I more or less have a separate tex file, which are `include`d in a main file.
The journal I'm submitting to now asks me to integrate all files in a single file.
I'm just wondering, isn't this quite bad practice? I mean, there's a reason for LaTeX to provide `include` commands.

This is not so much of a question, but I was just hoping to hear some opinions.

Comment: It makes it much easier for a production editor's workflow if all the code is in one file. As a producton editor I've wasted a lot of time going through each file to replace a problematic obsolete command or trying to work out which of the included files a particular problem is in.

Comment: `\include` is not for sections (beside others it forces a `\newpage`). And imho it is not suitable for articles. And in case you meant `\input`: It depends on the length of the article and your workflow. I general prefer not to split my documents in to many parts.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I get that it must be an effort, but isn't that the job of the production team? After all, we're paying close to USD 2000 for it.

Comment: @TMOTTM I'm a volunteer production editor, so I don't get paid for it. Those who do get paid may well be more willing to do that extra effort.

Comment: Remember also that journals (and authors) are keen to have a rapid turnaround so the longer it takes to process the files, the longer it takes to publish the journal. There is also the danger that a journal may decide that the effort (and cost) involved isn't worth their while and as a result they may decide not to accept LaTeX submissions and move over to a solely Word-based production line.

Comment: While my view is biased for sure, I still believe offering a production environment that caters towards people using Latex would definitely make the journal attractive. They also require me to remove all figure legends from the text and add them to separate input fields on the submission form where no special characters can be entered. I think a scientific journal should keep in mind that it's scientists who want to publish there.

Comment: in any case, the journal would not want to use `\include` commands, since by definition they start a new page.  using `\input` is more acceptable (for some journals), but the more work a production editor/team has to do on an article, the greater the possibility that new errors may be inadvertently introduced.  i'm sure you don't want that.  the best results are produced when a competent author delivers a very clean file following all the journal's guidelines.

Comment: I would follow all guidelines as cleanly as is possible, if there were any. In fact, they write one should upload source tex **files** as primary files, which clearly indicates that multiple files are accepted.

Comment: One approach might be using http://ctan.org/pkg/arlatex. `arlatex --outfile=a.tex -document=b.tex c.tex d.tex`

Answer (score 1):

As a general practice I like to use `\include` to keep everything clean and tidy, specially because it allows me to include just the files I want.

That said, when you have a large document, you can use `\includeonly{chapter1,chapter2}` and that will make ignore the rest of things and only compile chapter 1 and 2.

Now, if they are asking you to have everything in one file just comply... Maybe it's because of file storage purposes that they are asking it (or perhaps they just don't want to have a lot of files associated with one author).

Either way, you can also have a look at this post [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for more information about `\include` and several files projects.

Comment: please note -- `\include` and `\includeonly` are suitable for books, but not for journal articles.

Comment: Working in one large multi-thousand line document is much less convenient then having the document split up into semantic sections. I dont think the inserted newpages by `include` should be a problem, the article is buing built from scratch anyway by the production team

Answer (score 0):

They probably don't use TeX in their publishing process but (most probably - are you talking about an AIP journal?) XML. And they probably have scripts that convert the input to XML - it's a pain to write them in such a way that all eventualities are considered.

I am using pgfplots and tikz to do my plots and thus I had to combine everything into one file when submitting. I wrote a perl script that parses csv input files and outputs LaTeX code. But in the end, I had to submit all the graphics as pdf after all: their TeX engine choked on my files even though all the other online-compilers and my local installation ran without complaining. Couldn't manage to get it working...

Anyway, here is the perl script in case you're interested. Remember: it only parses the files and outputs LaTeX code - it doesn't actually combine all the snippets. It's quick and dirty, but a good starting point if you want to have a go.

My advice: just copy the biblatex and everything else in one file as the absolutely last step and submit the graphics as PDFs.

```
#! C:/Programme/Perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;

unless(@ARGV<1){ # Check if input file is given as a commandline argument
    open(FILE,"<".$ARGV[0]) or die("Error reading file: ".$ARGV[0]." ".$!);
    my $textraw="";
    while(<FILE>){$textraw.=$_;}
    close(FILE) or die("Error closing file: ".$ARGV[0]." ".$!);
    my $patternMatch;
    my @addplot;
    my $n=0;
    while($textraw =~ /(\\addplot.*?)table\[(.*?)?,?\s?x expr\=(.*?),y expr\=(.*?)\]\n\s+\{([^\}]*)\}/sg){
        $patternMatch++;
        my $plotCommand=$1;
        my $skipRows=$2;
        my @xCol;
        $xCol[0]=$3;
        my @yCol;
        $yCol[0]=$4;
        my $DataFileName=$5;
        if($skipRows){$skipRows=~s/skip first n=(\d)/$1/g;}
        else{$skipRows=0;}
        open(FILE,"<".$DataFileName) or die("Error reading file: ".$DataFileName." ".$!);
            my $i;
            #$addplot[$n]=$1."coordinates {";
            print $1."coordinates {";
            LINE:while(<FILE>){
                my $xCoord;
                my $yCoord;
                chomp($_);
                $i++;
                if($i<=$skipRows){next LINE;}
                if(($xCol[0]=~m/\\thisrow\{/)||($yCol[0]=~m/\\thisrow\{/)){
                    # I was going to put logic here to account for people using \thisrow.
                    # Screw this - it's too much hassle. Please use \thisrowno
                    die("Error: \thisrow{} detected - unable to parse. Please change LaTeX source to \thisrowno.");
                }
                my $xColStack=0;
                my $xOperator="+";
                my $xColTmp=$xCol[0];
                while($xColTmp=~/\\thisrowno\{(.*?)\}(.*)?/g){
                    my $columnIndex=$1;
                    my $additionalDirectives=$2;
                    $xColTmp=$additionalDirectives;
                    $_=~m/\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?/;
                    my %selectColumn = (
                        0 => $1,
                        1 => $2,
                        2 => $3,
                        3 => $4,
                        4 => $5,
                        5 => $6,
                        6 => $7,
                        7 => $8,
                        8 => $9,
                        9 => $10,
                        10 => $11,
                        11 => $12,
                        12 => $13,
                        13 => $14,
                        14 => $15
                    );
                    if($xOperator eq "+"){
                        $xColStack+=$selectColumn{$columnIndex};
                    }
                    else{
                        die("Unsupported operator - you have to implement it yourself. I only added \"+\".")
                    }
                    if($additionalDirectives=~/(.)?\d?\\thisrowno/){
                        $xOperator=$1;
                    }
                    elsif($additionalDirectives=~/(.)\s*?(\d*)/){
                        #die "[".$additionalDirectives."]";
                        #$xColStack=$xColStack;
                        die("There are some additional operations to be executed on the data, namely: $additionalDirectives \n Please use awk to format the data as this cannot be parsed. awk usage is as follows:\n gawk \"{\$1=\$1*1000;\$2=\\\"\\\";$\3=$\3*12e-3*1e-6/284;print}\" file.in > file.out");
                    }
                }
                #$addplot[$n].="(".$xColStack.",";
                print "(".$xColStack.",";
                my $yColStack=0;
                my $yOperator="+";
                my $yColTmp=$yCol[0];
                while($yColTmp=~/\\thisrowno\{(.*?)\}(.*)?/g){
                    my $columnIndex=$1;
                    my $additionalDirectives=$2;
                    print $2;
                    $yColTmp=$additionalDirectives;
                    $_=~m/\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?\s*(\S*)?/;
                    my %selectColumn = (
                        0 => $1,
                        1 => $2,
                        2 => $3,
                        3 => $4,
                        4 => $5,
                        5 => $6,
                        6 => $7,
                        7 => $8,
                        8 => $9,
                        9 => $10,
                        10 => $11,
                        11 => $12,
                        12 => $13,
                        13 => $14,
                        14 => $15
                    );
                    if($yOperator eq "+"){
                        $yColStack+=$selectColumn{$columnIndex};
                    }
                    else{
                        die("Unsupported operator - you have to implement it yourself. I only added \"+\".")
                    }
                    if($additionalDirectives=~/(.)?\d?\\thisrowno/){
                        $yOperator=$1;
                    }
                    elsif($additionalDirectives=~/(.)\s*?(\d*)/){
                        #die "[".$additionalDirectives."]";
                        #$xColStack=$xColStack;
                    }
                }
                #$addplot[$n].=$yColStack.")";
                print $yColStack.")";
            }
            #$addplot[$n].="};";
            print "};\n\n";
        close(FILE) or die("Error closing file: ".$DataFileName." ".$!);
        #$n++;
    }
    #$n=0;
    #while($textraw =~ /(\\addplot.*?)table\[.*?\]\n\s+\{.*?\}/sg){
    #   
    #   $n++;
    #}
}
else{print "Error: no input file given!\n\nUsage: $0 inputfile.\n";}
```

Comment: even if a publisher *does* use tex exclusively, the more pieces a job is delivered in, the greater the possibility that something will get lost, not be delivered, be misnamed, ...  all these things slow down the process.  the best advice i can offer is to always follow the publisher's guidelines, run the job one last time *with only the files that will be delivered* (except for "standard" packages, which should *not* be included in the collection submitted) to make sure that it runs smoothly, and package everything into a zip file to minimize the chance of loss.

Comment: It's a bit different in my case, the publisher claims to be incapable of processing tex files, which I find rather surprising, given the fact that it's a scientific publisher. Arxiv.org for example can handle any kind of tex construct I submitted so far with ease.

Comment: If they are indeed incapable of processing TeX files, why do they allow you to hand in one? Or are they saying: hand in a PDF file?